# Prestashop SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied

Tags: prestashop, centos7, prestashop1.7

Mi proyecto estaba en un Hosting compartido y lo subi a un VPS, realice los cambios en la base de datos y en parameters de mi tienda pero me sigue mostrando un error:

```
[PrestaShopException]
Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 
'xxxx_xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at line 127 in file classes/db/DbPDO.php
```

Pero ese usuario ***'xxxx_xxxx'@'localhost'*** era el usuario viejo que yo tenia en mi hosting.

[image: ErrorBackOffice]

**Lo que he intentado:**

1. Asegurarme que los datos en **/app/config/parameters.php** esten bien escritos.

**Edit:** he intentado agregando database_host:127.0.0.1 y database_port: 3306, recibiendo en ambos casos la misma respuesta.

```
    'database_host' => 'localhost',
    'database_port' => '',
    'database_name' => 'admin_newdatabase',
    'database_user' => 'admin_newuser',
    'database_password' => 'newpassword',
    'database_prefix' => 'ps_',
    'database_engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'mailer_transport' => 'smtp',
    'mailer_host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'mailer_user' => NULL,
    'mailer_password' => NULL,
```

2. Cambiar en la base de datos las rutas del nuevo dominio:

[image: CambioBD1]

[image: CambioBD2]

3. Siguiendo la recomendacion de este POST en prestashop https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/997334-solved-prestashop-17-database-wont-change/

Antes de borrar las carpetas "dev" y "prod" ubicado en **/var/cache/**

El log de errores me mostraba lo siguiente:

[ErrorLogAntesdeBorrarCarpetas](https://www.sendspace.com/file/wv06lo)

Despues de borrar estas carpetas el problema que menciono del usuario viejo desaparece, pero en lugar me muestra un error HTTP 500. En el log de errores recibo lo siguiente:

[ErrorLogDespuesdeBorrarCarpetas](https://www.sendspace.com/file/okcihq)

**Algunos datos adicionales:**

*He creado la base de datos usando CyberPanel Centos 7.

A pesar de revisar todo esto sigo sin entender porque al tratar de ingresar a mi backoffice me muestra ese mensaje de error con el usuario anterior de la base de datos.

Parece ser que este es un error muy frecuente a la hora de migrar un sitio Prestashop, alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo?

Gracias!

Comment: 'database_port' => '3306', falta puerto

Comment: Hola @manrriquemenesesyaranga gracias por tu aporte, voy editar la respuesta que intentado con y sin puerto, actualmente esta con puerto 3306. Gracias

Comment: En los nuevos logs por lo que veo no tienes ya el error de MySQL, veo errores y warnings de PHP. ¿Te aseguraste de estar usando la misma versión de PHP que usabas en el hosting? Muchas veces (hablo por Dinahosting donde estoy) se desea migrar de un hosting a otro o de un hosting a un VPS y al poder cambiar de versiones de PHP sin problema, suele tener la versión de PHP más reciente en el destino. Con lo que si tenías unas versiones más antiguas podría provocar este tipo de fallos. Intenta verificar que estés usando la misma en el destino que la que usabas en el origen.

Comment: Comparto lo que dice @Adrián. Ademas puedes hacer `sudo yum update` en CentOS y actualizar todos los repo, incluyendo PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Hola he tenido un error similar o el mismo varias veces con diferentes web y migraciones, etc.

Yo personalmente no cambiaría la url del sitio, en la base de datos.

Lo que yo haría de esta manera:

Montar la web original en local.

En la base de datos solo desactivaría SSL, buscaria

```
SELECT * FROM ps_configuration pc WHERE name LIKE '%ssl%'`
```

y pondría *value* a 0

Entraría en el back-office: Parámetros de la Tienda -> Trafico SEO -> Establecer URL de la tienda y cambias el dominio.

Cuando cambias de domino Prestashop genera varios archivos, entre ellos htaccess y otros.